# Grab Text From Dynamically Created UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to grab the text from a dynamically created text field. I use this to make the text field become and resign first responder:

```
[(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:0] becomeFirstResponder];
```

That works fine, but when I try to get the text, the app crashes.

```
[(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:0] text];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the exception that gets thrown causing the app to crash? I am guessing it's something along the lines of: <blah> does not respond to selector text

Comment: -[UITableView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x601fe00 self.view is a UITableView, but I don't know why it thinks I am trying to get 'text' from the UITableView since I asked for a UITextView with tag 0 and it works fine with becomeFirstResponder/resignFirstResponder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the tag 0. `viewWithTag:` searches the view hierarchy starting from itself and since all views start with tag 0, it will identify itself as the view to be returned.

I suggest that you use a different tag on the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default tag for every UIView is 0, I'm going to guess that there are multiple UIViews with the same tag (tags aren't guaranteed to be unique). Instead, choose an arbitrary high value like 1000, then increment that with each view added.

Also, it would help if you included your UITextField creation code.